# Ember Push Ds.InvalidError to model instance

Tags: ajax, api, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I get a Ds.InvalidError from custom Ajax request with 422 status code and it contents the errors array into Ds.InvalidError.errors property

How push the errors to model instance if the model_instance.errors property is only-read?

References: The app is running under Ember 2.4 and [ember-api-action](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions) version 0.1.2

```
actions: {
  recoverPasswordA: function(user) {
    var self = this;
    user.recoverPassword(user.serialize()).then(
      function(response) {
        self.store.pushPayload('user', response);
      },
      function(xhr) {
        var errors = xhr.errors;
        var recordErrors = user.get('errors');
        for (var key in errors) {
          if (!errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            continue;
          }
          recordErrors.add(key, errors[key]);
        }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I solved it, the problem here, errors is an array and the xhr is a DS.invalidError object, just changed the key and errors[key] with the correct path to pointer and detail

Answer (score 0):

I should be done like this,

```
model.get('errors').add('error_name', 'Error text');
```

Comment: Yes I did that, but show a warning saying the record state not changed. and not show the errors in the template.

Comment: Can you post your code, it would be easier to solve your problem.

Comment: yes. I edited the ask, and the user instance doesnt show the errors in template